# Batch Rename Keys

Tags: redis

I have a rather large database (5 dbs of about a million keys each), and each key has the environment namespace in it. For example: `"datamine::production::crosswalk==foobar"`

I need to sync my **development** environment with this data copied from the production RDB snapshot.

So what I'm trying to do is batch rename every key, changing the namespace from `datamine::production` to `datamine::development`. Is there a good, way to achieve this?

#### What I've tried so far

- redis-cli command of `keys "datamine::production*"`, piped into sed, then back to `redis-cli`. This takes forever, and bombs for some reason on many keys (combining several in the same line, sporadically). I'd prefer a better option.
- Perl search/replace on the .rdb file. My local redis-server flat refuses to load the modified RDB.

Comment: I'd go with "get all keys and toss them to RENAME command". Only I'd use SCAN instead of KEYS (more efficient). Also instead of sed I'd use ruby

Comment: Ok, I'm going to create a ruby script for this, and I'll put it here for the world to use... (unless someone wants to beat me to it!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The solution:

Ok, here's the script I wrote to solve this problem. It requires the "Redis" gem. Hopefully someone else finds this useful...

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# A script to translate the current redis database into a namespace for another environment
# GWI's Redis keys are namespaced as "datamine::production", "datamine::development", etc.
# This script connects to redis and translates these key names in-place.
#
# This script does not use Rails, but needs the "redis" gem available
require 'Benchmark'
require 'Redis'

FROM_NAMESPACE = "production"
TO_NAMESPACE = "development"
NAMESPACE_PREFIX = "datamine::"
REDIS_SERVER = "localhost"
REDIS_PORT   = "6379"
REDIS_DBS = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

redis = Redis.new(host: REDIS_SERVER, port: REDIS_PORT, timeout: 30)

REDIS_DBS.each do |redis_db|
  redis.select(redis_db)
  puts "Translating db ##{redis_db}..."
  seconds = Benchmark.realtime do
    dbsize = redis.dbsize.to_f
    inc_threshold = (dbsize/100.0).round
    i = 0
    old_keys = redis.keys("#{NAMESPACE_PREFIX}#{FROM_NAMESPACE}*")
    old_keys.each do |old_key|
      new_key = old_key.gsub(FROM_NAMESPACE, TO_NAMESPACE)
      redis.rename(old_key, new_key)
      print "#{((i/dbsize)*100.0).round}% complete\r" if (i % inc_threshold == 0) # on whole # % only
      i += 1
    end
  end
  puts "\nDone. It took #{seconds} seconds"
end
```

Comment: For batch actions like this, I recommend pipelining. If you flush/execute every 500 iterations or so, you'll most probably improve the performance by a factor 40 to 50, with almost no effort.

Answer (score 5):

I have a working solution:

```
EVAL "local old_prefix_len = string.len(ARGV[1])
local keys = redis.call('keys', ARGV[1] .. '*')
for i = 1, #keys do
    local old_key = keys[i]
    local new_key = ARGV[2] .. string.sub(old_key, old_prefix_len + 1)
    redis.call('rename', old_key, new_key)
end" 0 "datamine::production::" "datamine::development::"
```

Two last parameters are respectively an old prefix and a new prefix.

Comment: This did work, only it locks the server until it is done, so I had a 5 minutes down time on a server with lots of keys to be renamed. So watch out, it is not an async command

Comment: Excellent! This worked. I only had to put all commands on a single line for redis-cli. Is there another way to run this as well?